# Binomial distribution (i think)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

This may seem like a simple question but I honestly don't really know how I would go about solving it.
So essentially the question is as follows:

2 players play a match whereby the winner is the first person to win n games.

the probability of player 1 winning a single game is 0.835
the probability of player 2 winning a single game is 0.165

what is the smallest value for n such that the probability that player 1 is the overall winner of the match is at least 0.9

---

I feel like i need to use binomial distribution to solve the question but i wasn't able to do so.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "2 players play a game whereby the winner is the first person to win n games." -> Hmmm, I sense an infinite regress where no one will be a winner ever .... unless $n=0$ ... although that might lead to a contradiction?

Comment: hey, I edited the question, essentially 2 players play a match which consists of multiple games e.g. a football match whereby the overall winner is the first person to win n matches.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that was my point :) Anyway, here is how I would approach this problem. First, it is clear that with $n=1$ this is not going to work. OK, so move to $n=2$: what is the probability that player $1$ gets to $2$ wins before player $2$ does? And for that, think of the different ways in which player 1 would win. This already might give you the answer (given how close 0.835 is already to 0.9, I would not be surprised .... but I leave to it to you to do the calculation.

Comment: so you recommend that i should solve the problem using trial and error? is there any way of solving the question using equations etc.

Comment: Yes, this problem would be a lot more interesting if you couldn't quickly settle it by a small $n$ ... and instead would need some general formula. And for that yes, you're absolutely right, the different ways in which player 1 can win would make use of the binomial distribution. Indeed, in general,  the number of ways player 1 would win in exactly $n$ games is nCn=1. The number of ways of winning it in n+1 games is nC(n-1) (player 1 had to win n+1-th game, and n-1 of the first n games). etc.

Comment: But with binomial distribution equation don't we need to have a fixed number of trials? as in, what confuses me here is that we don't have a fixed number of matches etc. so how would u be able to use the equation in such place. (Sorry that it seems like im trying to fish out the answer, but i just want to get some hints as to what i should do or look into to be able to use the binomial equation for such case.)

Comment: Just gave you a hint. Yes, there is no fixed number of games ... but in order to win, you have to win in n games, or n+1 games, or n+2 games or .... or 2n-1 games. Now, the last game has to be a win for player 1, but the other n-1 games have to be scattered among the earlier games. So, you get a *sum* of term, where each term has a simple binomial formula.  Also, take a look at this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955211/probability-to-get-5-successes-in-at-most-7-trials/3955669#3955669

Comment: thank u so much, i think i have a better view of the question now.

Comment: You're welcome!  And, did you find that $n=2$ is enough? :)

Comment: oh my bad i just went to eat so i didn't even do it haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bram28's hints point in the right direction. Still, a more general formulation would be helpful for posterity.

Say that player 1 wins the match (i.e., they are the first to win $n$ games), and player 2 wins $k < n$ games. The probability that this happens (given that player 1 wins a game with probability $p$) is

$$\text{Prob}_{n, k}(p) = p\binom{n+k-1}{n-1} p^{n-1} q^{k}$$

We use $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$ rather than $\binom{n+k}{n}$ because if player 1 wins the match, they must win the *final* game and thus there are only the remaining $n-1$ game wins to be distributed amongst the $n+k-1$ possible game slots. The initial factor of $p$ is the probability of player 1 wining the final game; the $p^{n-1}q^{k}$ factor is the probability of player 1 wining $n-1$ and losing $k$ prior games.

The probability that player 1 is the first to win $n$ games is the sum of the above quantity over the possible values of $k$, that is

$$\text{Prob of player 1 winning match} =   p^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}  q^{k}. $$

We could find a closed form expression for the summation by differentiating the identity for a finite geometric series, but here it's easier to just plug in values. For $n=1$, we find 0.835 which isn't sufficient. For $n=2$, we find

\begin{align}
\text{Prob of player 1 winning match} &= (0.835)^2\left[\binom{2-1}{2-1} (0.165)^0 + \binom{2+1-1}{2-1}(0.165)^1\right]\\
& = 0.9273,
\end{align}

which is.

Comment: thank you for the answer, just one thing to add, i think u might have forgotten to put the "initial factor p" that you mentioned in your first equation. Apart from that, the response answered my question perfectly so thank u so much!

Comment: @m3hran Thanks. Corrected the typo

Comment: @motherboard: Pl note that this more complex formulation yields **exactly the same result** as my simpler one, you can try and puzzle it out ! *Hint*: The first term amounts to ${0.835}^2 *1$  which can be expanded as ${0.835}^2*(0.835 +0.165)$

Comment: Pl see some additional material I have provided

Answer (score 2):

With $p = 0.835, 2$ games are obviously not enough, because A would need to win both games, with a $Pr = {0.835}^2 <0.9$, so trials can begin from number of games played, $K = 3$

You would find computations much simpler if you focus on the **losses** of $A$ rather than wins.

For example, with $K=3$, $A$ can afford to lose **at most** one game, so the probability of an overall win is $\binom30q^0p^3 + \binom31q^1p^2$, which happily works out to

$\binom30 0.165^0\cdot 0.835^3 + \binom310.165^1\cdot0.835^2 = 0.9273$

thus the smallest value of *n* (games won) needed $=2$

---

### Response to queries

We are trying to use the smallest number of games $(K)$ so we can find the smallest number of wins ($n$) needed.

With $K=3$, we found $n=2$ is possible if we include  more than $2$ wins in the series of $K$ games.

If we want to strictly say that more than $n$ wins can't be included in the probability calculations, the formula will change to $\binom{K}{n} p^nq^{K-n} \geq 0.9$

A little thought will show that with this formula, the *Pr* will **never** reach $0.9$, even for $n=2$, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table+C%28K%2C2%29*0.835%5E2*0.165%5E%28K-2%29+K+%3D+2+to+10)

So either we'll have to allow  more than $n$ wins in the *Pr* computations, else it is impossible.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to use $n$ in a way different from how it is used in the problem statement. In your answer $n$ is the total number of games while in the problem statement it is the total number of times player 1 wins.

Comment: @motherboard:You have a point. I am changing the numberof games played to $K$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Than you for your explanation. I just have a question about it. If the number of games required to be won for the players to be the overall winner is 2, then won't that mean that we shouldn't include 3 wins in our calculation? as after the first 2 wins player A will be declared the winner and there won't be any need for him to play another game?

Comment: I have added material addressed to this query